# Using angular-chart.js as a dependency in a custom mean.io package

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

First of all, I installed angular-chart.js as suggested.

http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

From the directory of my custom mean package I typed:

```
$ bower install angular-chart.js --save
```

That created several folders in the public/assets folder of my custom module.

```
/packages/custom/report/public/assets/lib/angular-chart.js/...
and
/packages/custom/report/public/assets/lib/Chart.js/...
```

I followed the instructions from learn.mean.io on how to add an angular dependency to a custom mean package.

http://learn.mean.io/#mean-stack-packages-angular-modules-and-dependencies

In my module's app.js:

```
// Aggregate CSS assets
Report.aggregateAsset('css', 'report.css');
Report.aggregateAsset('css', '../lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css');

// Aggregate JS assets
Report.aggregateAsset('js','../lib/Chart.js/Chart.js');
Report.aggregateAsset('js','../lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js');

// Add dependency to modules in the custom package
Report.angularDependencies(['chart.js']);
```

In theory, that would be equal to defining my module like this, including the dependency:

```
angular.module('mean.report', ['chart.js']);
```

Which I also tried by the way.

When I run the application I can see that the JS and CSS files are downloaded, the CSS styles can be used, but I can not see any charts.

Trying many different ways of configuration at mean.io files I've been able to see a pie chart, but every time I try to feed it with real data I get some errors like Chart is not defined, etc. It's crazy that I change a line in a view of my app and the chart dissappears. I can't get it working in a consistent way.

So, either chart.js doesn't get injected in my module or the dependencies between angular-chart.js and Chart.js are not resolved.

I discussed for long with a guy from mean.io support team and he said everything was ok on the mean side, and that I probably should check angular-chart.js

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like Chart.js isn't being included properly or out of order. Have you tried including the scripts directly into your view instead of through the aggregateAsset method?

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/master/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

I got the demo working fairly easily here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/uc25erpc/. If you load angular-chart before Chart.js, I get the same error you had of Chart is not being defined.

On another note, check out https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS for an alternative AngularJS wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working with a different module, the googlechart module.

Module installation:

```
$ bower install angular-google-chart --save
```

In my module's app.js:

```
// Add CSS dependencies
// Module's CSS
Report.aggregateAsset('css', 'report.css');

// Add angular module dependencies
// Dependency to 'googlechart' module adding directives for Google Chart
// See https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart
Report.aggregateAsset('js', '../lib/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js');
```

Custom module controller:

```
angular.module('mean.report', ['googlechart'])
.controller('ReportController', ['$scope', 'Global', 
  function($scope, Global) {
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to avoid the error message "Chart is not defined".

Use `bower_components` instead of `aggregateAsset` functions. Put the following lines within your `config/assets.json` file, in the same order as the "js" section:

```
    "bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.min.js",
    "bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"
```

And define required dependency in your app.js:

```
    Report.angularDependencies(['chart.js']);
```